# Error while delete all the rows and keep a selected rows in SQL table

Tags: sql, r, database, dataframe

I have a SQL file and I want to remove all the rows and just select one based on a condition.

My SQL look like this:

```
dput(brain_cortex_gtex_n[1:5,c(1,2,6)])
structure(list(gene = c("ENSG00000130943.6", "ENSG00000130943.6", 
"ENSG00000130943.6", "ENSG00000130943.6", "ENSG00000130943.6"
), rsid = c("rs6007530", "rs7364174", "rs6007567", "rs112187135", 
"rs144824037"), weight = c(0.0671656140385751, 0.065292861996415, 
0.0088563732779068, -0.3156608259595, 0.0128894490022945)), row.names = 8154:8158, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to select only the row in which rsid is equal to "rs3087501"
The code that I wrote is:

```
x <- which(gtex_n$rsid %in% "rs3087501") ##x is 8222

#copy original file db to another
#use that for modifications: 
library("RSQLite")
sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
dbname <- "gtex_v7_models_filtered_signif.db" 
db = dbConnect(sqlite,dbname)
sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
myfile <- paste0("gtex_filtered_brain_cortex_modelsn","_","rs3087501",".db")
dbname1 <- myfile
db1 = dbConnect(sqlite,dbname1)
sqliteCopyDatabase(db, db1)
dbDisconnect(db)
brain_cortex_gtex_n_1 <- dbGetQuery(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights") ##dim 9453
#dbExecute(db1,"DELETE FROM weights WHERE rsid=rsid[i] ") 
dbExecute(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights WHERE rsid="rs3087501")
dbDisconnect(db1)
```

But I get an error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "dbExecute(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights WHERE rsid="rs3087501"

Does anyone know how to solve this or provide any guidance for it.

Thank you.

Comment: Problem is with unbalanced quotes: `dbExecute(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights WHERE rsid="rs3087501")` should be `dbExecute(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights WHERE rsid='rs3087501'")`

Comment: I just want to keep this particular rsid and remove all the unmatched one. After this, it keeps all the rows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: this answer builds and corrects one piece at a time, not all interim code blocks are completely correct. Go to the bottom for the final recommend(s).

1. The error is because you have mismatched quotes: all double-quotes must be matched, and if you need embedded double-quotes, then you have two options: start with single quotes (since in R, `'hello'` and `"hello"` are perfectly identical) and use double quotes within; or use backslashed double quotes. For instance,

   ```r
   '"hello" world'
   # [1] "\"hello\" world"
   "\"hello\" world"
   # [1] "\"hello\" world"
   identical('"hello" world', "\"hello\" world")
   # [1] TRUE
   ```

   This means you could convert your string into one of these (though they are still wrong, keep reading):

   ```r
   dbExecute(db1,'SELECT * FROM weights WHERE rsid="rs3087501"')
   dbExecute(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights WHERE rsid=\"rs3087501\"")
   ```
2. SQL does not treat single-quotes and double-quotes synonymously, typically double-quotes are for *identifiers* (tables, column names) and single-quotes are for *string literals*. Instead, use (though still not completely correct):

   ```r
   dbExecute(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights WHERE rsid='rs3087501'")
   ```
3. If you really did mean `SELECT`, then you should be using `dbGetQuery` as you did earlier. I suspect you meant to use `DELETE` in that call to `dbExecute`, which would then translate into (still not the ideal answer, though getting closer):

   ```r
   dbExecute(db1,"DELETE FROM weights WHERE rsid='rs3087501'")
   ```
4. It is generally discouraged to `paste` or `sprintf` "data" things directly into a SQL query, for many reasons. You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

   This means you can do:

   ```r
   dbExecute(db1,"DELETE FROM weights WHERE rsid=?", params = list("rs3087501"))
   ```

   Note that in this case, we do *not* put quotes around the `?` marker, and the quotes used within the `list(.)` are solely for R, so it does not matter if you use single-quotes or double-quotes.
5. You say *"keep this particular rsid and remove all the unmatched one"*, which suggests deleting all others ... which means either (no need for both) of the following will work:

   ```r
   dbExecute(db1,"DELETE FROM weights WHERE not rsid=?", params = list("rs3087501"))
   dbExecute(db1,"DELETE FROM weights WHERE rsid <> ?", params = list("rs3087501"))
   ```

Fully reproducible example:

```r
sqlite <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())
DBI::dbWriteTable(sqlite, "mt", head(mtcars))
DBI::dbGetQuery(sqlite, "select * from mt")
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
DBI::dbExecute(sqlite, "delete from mt where not cyl=?", params=list(6))
# [1] 2
DBI::dbGetQuery(sqlite, "select * from mt")
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 4 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for this answer and detailed explanation. I appreciate it and will consider the feedback next time I am writing into SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

Just note your example is missing the rsid you want to filter for. If it was in there, this approach will work for filtering the data after the SQL query. For this example I replaced the first rsid with the one specified.

```
df <- structure(list(gene = c("ENSG00000130943.6", "ENSG00000130943.6", 
                        "ENSG00000130943.6", "ENSG00000130943.6", "ENSG00000130943.6"
), rsid = c("rs3087501", "rs7364174", "rs6007567", "rs112187135", 
            "rs144824037"), weight = c(0.0671656140385751, 0.065292861996415, 
                                       0.0088563732779068, -0.3156608259595, 0.0128894490022945)), row.names = 8154:8158, class = "data.frame")

output <- df %>% 
  filter(rsid == "rs3087501")
```

Comment: Hello, yes this one works for dataframe, but I need to filter the ids in sql file and store it as final model file